# Exchange + Python (Linux) SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server

Tags: python, sendmail, exchange

Добрый день!
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, не удается настроить авторизованную отправку внутри сети писем скриптом, не авторизованная отправляется.
у отправителя намеренно указан адрес local, alias существует.

Скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*-coding: utf-8 -*-
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
import smtplib
import sys
sender = 'test@domain.local' # От кого
recivers = 'test2@domain.local' # Кому
text = sys.argv[1]
msg = MIMEText(text, "", "utf-8")
msg["Subject"] = "Уведомление о пропущенном вызове"
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('ex.domain.ru', 25)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('test', '!Q2w3e4r-2015')
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, recivers, msg.as_string())
smtpObj.close()
```

Вывод ошибки:

```
[root@pbx-o ~]# python /usr/local/bin/sendmail.py qweqweq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sendmail.py", line 21, in <module>
    smtpObj.login('test', '!Q2w3e4r-2015')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 584, in login
    raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Вывод при обращение smtpObj.helo()

```
>>> smtpObj.helo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 401, in helo
    self.putcmd("helo", name or self.local_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 340, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 330, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('Server not connected')
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Server not connected
```

Comment: в сообщении об ошибке Вам указанно, что вы используете аутентификацию, которую не поддерживает сервер. например тлс обычно на 465 порту висит. в любом случае сделайте message = smtpobj.ehlo() и посмотрите, какие методы сервер укажет в используемых, оттуда и танцуйте

Comment: Скажите, как дальше быть?
Ответ от сервера:
>>> smtpObj.ehlo()
(250, 'mail.domain.ru says EHLO to XX.XX.XXX.XXX:33891\nSTARTTLS\nPIPELINING\nSIZE 100485760\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8BITMIME')

Comment: Если указываю порт 465:

Comment: >>> smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('ex.domain.ru', 465)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: информацию, необходимую для ответа в сам вопрос помещайте вместо комментариев.

Comment: вот [код, который для нескольких сервисов работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/369479/23044)

Comment: а smtpobj.helo() чего говорит на 25 порту(его нужно запускать первым)? потому как ehlo ничего необычного не возвращает