# Аналог PHP функции mail()

Tags: python-3.x

В PHP для отправки отчётов об ошибка на почту использовал функцию `mail()`. На Python для этого рекомендуют использовать `smtplib`, однако ей нужен внешний SMTP сервер. А можно ли обойтись без него?

Comment: Интересно, а как `mail` php работает...

Comment: Используйте SMTP Сервера Yandex, Google или ещё чьи-нибудь

Comment: *"однако ей нужен внешний SMTP сервер"* --  в smtplib.SMTP можно localhost в качестве сервера передать). Вот [пример для внешних известных сервисов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/369427/23044)

Comment: @Andru: credentials как обычно забирайте (что используете, к примеру, из переменных окружения)

Comment: При использовании localhost вылетает ошибка